# Apache vs Tomcat configuration question

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jakarta-ee, tomcat5.5

I was searching in Google and found that Apache can be configured via `mod_access` directives in the `httpd.conf` file to block a web site from a particular IP.
Is there anything equivalent in Tomcat?
I am not sure I understand what are the corresponding configuration files.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try the Remote Address Filter. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/valve.html

Answer (score 1):

See the Request filters section of this [doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/engine.html). Doing this via tomcat configuration is pretty static, you need to restart to edit configuration. If you need something dynamic, it's probably best to implement a custom servlet filter.